# Embedded board - Install debian

Tags: debian, linux-kernel, embedded

I'm new in embedded world and I'm quite confuse.

I have a Freescale board which contains an ARM926 32 Bits and mounts Linux 2.6.35.

First question: this is the kernel, right?

Second question:

I need to install debian in this board but I don't know how to do it because I can connect just with ssh. There's a slot in the board for a micro SD but I don't know if it can help me.

The board is: http://www.mect.it/en/products/control-and-automation/operator-panels-with-embedded-input-and-output-and-plc/tpac1007/

Answer (score 1):

Usually, on embedded device there are multiple options. 
If you already see a kernel 2.6.35 with a blank micro SD slot, it might mean that the system is stored in some flash memory on the board.

Usually the bootloader is setup to find system on different support, so i guess the easiest way to use debian is to buy an sd card, burn an debian image dedicated for your board and plug it in the micro-sd SLOT.

Reboot the board and the bootloader will detect debian on the micro SD and boots it. 
What is the name of the board ? look for a debian image to download for it.

Another option is to find a debian image for your board small enought to fit your flash memory and usually using USB you can burn it directly the flash memory.

The last option is to setup a full cross compilation environment on your desktop computer, and then build yourself your debian image. You should look about debian bootstrap and cross compilation for that, and of course at the technical spec of your board, especially the bootloader process.

Comment: I'll try your solutions, even if the last one is not so clear to me. However here there are the specs: http://www.mect.it/en/products/control-and-automation/operator-panels-with-embedded-input-and-output-and-plc/tpac1007/

Comment: https://github.com/MECTsrl/imx_mect there is not debian image for your card based on basic search debian and tpac1007 but you have the github repo of the constructor here : https://github.com/MECTsrl/imx_mect

Comment: This mean that I cannot install debian..And how should repo help me?